# Target parent element by class name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working with angular.

In  table cells I render variable structure of html so the DOM structure within each cell is not constant.

Within each cell I have content overflow hidden(all is shown on hover of the cell). An input field is within each cell as part of the content.

What I am trying to achieve is that when "tab" key is pressed, to go from the input of one cell to the input of the next cell, the parent "td"/cell of the input that just gained focus shows the overflow(expands).

Each "td" element has a directive:

```
myApp.directive('input', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {

            element.bind('focus', function(){
                console.log(element.parent()[0].style.overflow="visible");
                console.log(element.parent()[0].style.maxHeight="100%");

            });
            element.bind('blur', function(){
                console.log(element.parent()[0].style.overflow="hidden");
                console.log(element.parent()[0].style.maxHeight="30px");

            });
        }
    }
});
```

The directive doesn't do what I wish because the parent element targeted is not allways the right one(not allways the "td").

If I apply a class name to each "td" can't I do something like???:

```
element.parent('.className'));
```

It neither works when the input is a textarea.

http://jsfiddle.net/5m1a2Ljs/48/

Comment: Will you please provide a fiddle ?

Comment: Do you create the table using ng-repeat?

Comment: yes I do. Triple nested ng-repeat

Comment: You could avoid the DOM selection problem altogether by putting the directive on the table cell instead of the input field.  (In general you want to avoid doing direct DOM manipulation in angular whenever possible; use e.g.  `ng-focus,` `ng-blur,` `ng-class` and let Angular do the heavy lifting instead of doing all the work yourself)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an ancestor (not only the direct parent) element using a selector via jQuery, you can do

```
element.closest(SELECTOR)
```